# How to use my iPod nano 5G?

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation, ipod

I have a 5th generation nano and want to know how I can edit my playlists, add music, remove music, etc.

Also I read banshee is the default media player for 11.04, can it handle my question or do I need another app? Also how do I convert a video to the video iPod format? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: Yes, Banshee will serve those needs ([Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1267180&highlight=ipod%20nano%205g&page=33))

Banshee has had a history of being a decent linux alternative to iTunes, but it's still not perfect. [Apparently it didn't work in 2009](http://banshee-media-player.2283330.n4.nabble.com/iPod-Nano-5G-Support-td2983675.html), but now it does since the update of libgpod-0.8.0, which is standard on the latest install of Banshee.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Rythmbox or Banshee will do the job, but for those who need their Ipod initialized, this link: http://wired-news.blogspot.fr/2012/09/ipod-nano-5g-synchronization-issues-in.html might save you a lot of trouble. It basically creates a HashInfo file which will make Ubuntu players to recognize your Ipod.